# How to Print a Hidden Page TWICE in a PDF using LiveCycle Designer

Tags: javascript, printing, livecycle-designer

I'm developing forms with LiveCycle Designer and my colleague at work asked me this question.

I only could think of making a page visible in the `prePrint` - Event and hide it in the `postPrint` - Event. But I don't know how to multiply it during runtime.

Does anyone know of cool ways to do this with Javascript (Adobe JS)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depend on how you print- by using a button build in the PDF and print call in the onClick event or "normal" print.

If you use normal print you can affect the PDF by prePrint and postPrint events, like changing presence of the hidden objects. The easiest way would be here to duplicate the hidden page and make both pages visible in the prePrint event and hide them in the postPrint event.

Second way:

- Set you hidden page  text flow.
- Select every object on hidden page and enclose with a subform.
- In the binding option of the subform "Min count" under "Repeat Subform for Each Data Item" set to 1.
- In the rpePrint after you set visibility of the page to true add "PageName.SubformName.instanceManager.addInstance(1)"
- In the postPrint event remove add "PageName.SubformName.instanceManager.removeInstance(0)" and set visibility of the page to false.

But if you have a button inside the PDF-Document then you have could call [print](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/livecycle/9.0/designerHelp/index.htm?content=001234.html) function. You will have to call the function 2 times with different page-range depending on where the hidden page is

Comment: Do you know the actual Javascript Code for duplicating a page?
I just tried 

`drucken.presence = "visible";
drucken.instanceManager.addInstance(1);` 
and also without a parameter but only one instance of that page is showing.
I'm using the normal Print in this case.

Comment: Subform1.instanceManager.addInstance(true); // Default instance manager syntax

Comment: With the steps I described you aren't actually make a second instance of the page, but of the second instance of the subform(with all element of the page) which in flow content typed Subform will result in expanding your page